# Is C++ OTL SQL database library using parameterized queries under the hood, or string concat?

Tags: c++, sql, parameterized, otl

I've been looking at the OTL (Oracle, Odbc and DB2-CLI Template Library) for C++ database access.  I'm unsure of whether the query I pass in is converted to a parameterized query for the underlying database, or if it's basically just concatenating all the arguments into one big string and passing the query to the database that way.  I see that the query you pass in to it can include type information for the arguments, but what happens between then and the query hitting the database, I can't tell.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=OTL+library) returns about a zillion different "OTL Library" -s. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Ken: Oops -- the other ones appear to be the kind of libraries with books :P

Comment: @Billy Sorry for the confusion.  Oracle Template Library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### OTL author's response to my e-mail:

OTL passes queries with placeholders into the DB API layers. The naming conventions for actual bind variables are different for different DB types. Say, for Oracle,

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname=:f_name<char[20]>
```

will be translated into:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname=:f_name
```

plus a bunch of host variable bind calls.

For MS SQL Server, or DB2, the same SELECT would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname=?
```

It's described in the manual that you can't have a placeholder with the same name more than once for MS SQL, DB2. SQL statements with placeholder / bind variables are relatively expensive to create, so if you instantiate an parameterized SQL via an otl_stream, it makes sense to reuse the stream as much as you can.

If you have more questions, or suggestions on how I can improve the OTL manual, feel free to email me.

Cheers,
Sergei

pheadbaq wrote:

Hi, I've been evaluating C++ DB libraries recently to use as a base for an ORM library I wish to build, and have been gravitating more and more towards the OTL.  It looks very nice by the way, and seems like it would meet most of the needs I have.  I just have one lingering question that I can't seem to clarify by reading the docs.  Does OTL pass a parameterized query on to the underlying DBMS, or is it concatenating the arguments and query I pass to the OTL stream into a single string and hand that to the DBMS?

In other words, if I hand OTL this MSSQL query, along with with the string "Bob" as the bind variable:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname = :f_name<char[20]>
```

Does the OTL parser produce this:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname = 'Bob'
```

Or this:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname = @f_name
```

along with my string as a parameter

I've posted this same question to StackOverflow.com if you care to respond there:
[Is C++ OTL SQL database library using parameterized queries under the hood, or string concat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149974/is-c-otl-sql-database-library-using-parameterized-queries-under-the-hood-or-st)

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hiii Sergei... well the manual is good, just the format is a bit tricky. As for some optimisations, when we write OTL string used with place holders, you somehow offered the freedom to interlace placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_bind_variables.htm) talks all about bind variables. I assume that the library *is* rewriting your query, but it's probably just changing the format of the bind variables into the format your DBMS expects, and then binding the values to the bind variables.

Comment: That's what I would hope, but I've read the docs a few times now, and I'm just not sure.  It's a tossup to me whether OTL is simply using string-based placeholders to concat the values I pass in and translate to the correct SQL dialect for XYZ DBMS, or if it's translating to the correct dialect AND the correct way of defining a parameterized query for XYZ DBMS.

Comment: @pheadbaq: Certainly, they wrote a library that's safe from SQL injection attacks either way.

Comment: @Ken not trying to be a pain, but I don't see how translating to the correct DBMS dialect automatically means injection safety.

If I hand OTL a string and it passes WHERE fname = 'bob' to the DMBS as opposed to WHERE fname = @f_name, then I need to protect against injection myself.

Comment: Sent a message to the library author, I'll post a response if he answers back.

Comment: Posted the response I got from the author.  I'm happy to say you were right, Ken. :)  I just didn't want to go on an assumption by myself or others, but now we know.

Comment: @pheadbaq: In general, I would assume that a DB layer that supports bind variables is actually binding the variables at the driver level. However, if a DB layer is emulating bind variables (interpolating them into the query itself, and not just passing it on to the driver), then I would assume that it knows how to escape the strings properly, so as to avoid an injection attack.