# Is MySQL Connector C++ cgi program vulnerable to MySQL injection just like php is?

Tags: c++, mysql, security, cgi, mysql-connector

I am making a **cgi** program using **C++**. It allows users to **register** their information on the website and also login. I am worried about **security**. Normally, MySQL is vulnerable to MySQL injection when using **php** to receive form. I am using the **MySQL Connector/C++** API.

When using **C++**, does the method of **MySQL injection** work on **cgi** programs? Is the **C++ cgi** program still **vulnerable** to **MySQL injection**?

I know that **cgi** programs has their own **security problems** such as **buffer overflow** but I am asking about **MySQL security**.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is Yes. Since c++ are not popular on website programming, it does have as many exposures as php. But you still need santinize your values before passing them to SQL., Even you use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes exactly SQL Injection is not language dependent. C++ is also vulnerable to c++ Injection. It actually depend to on the logic you use for querying the database not the language.

For preventing from SQL injection you have few methods to follow.

Primary Defenses:

```
Option #1: Use of Prepared Statements (Parameterized Queries)
Option #2: Use of Stored Procedures
Option #3: Escaping all User Supplied Input
```

Additional Defenses:

```
Also Enforce: Least Privilege
Also Perform: White List Input Validation
```

you can refer these links for further details.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
[Is C++ OTL SQL database library using parameterized queries under the hood, or string concat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149974/is-c-otl-sql-database-library-using-parameterized-queries-under-the-hood-or-s)

Comment: Now, I know that I am not safe. Thanks for the links.