# I cannot use insert and select at the same time using mysql database connection .C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I would like to know how do I copy column from one table to another another table using mysql database connection?

My code is like this:

```
string insert_query = "insert into customer_info (Customer Name, Price) Select name,price from medicine_tb where id = '"+storeid[j]+"'"; 

const char* qu = insert_query.c_str();
qstate = mysql_query(conn, qu);
```

But it is NOT working!

Comment: What's the error message? "It is NOT working" is not really helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is MySQL Connector C++ cgi program vulnerable to MySQL injection just like php is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431877/is-mysql-connector-c-cgi-program-vulnerable-to-mysql-injection-just-like-php-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
insert into customer_info (`Customer Name`, Price)
```